# SSRS Report Parameter Available Values setting

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to set Available Values on SSRS Report Parameter properties.
I wish I can add some images but I do not enough reputation.

When I select `'Get values from a query'`, I don't have problem.
However, I get this message when I am trying to use `'Specify values'`

> "Field cannot be used in report parameter expressions."

I am using following expression. Any help would be appreciated.

```
=First(Fields!EventCode1.Value, "History2")
```

Comment: Parameter value expressions cannot access datasets in that way. But before I can help you, can you describe at a higher level what you're attempting to do? What sort of parameters are you trying to devise? How are you wanting the available values to be generated?

Comment: Comment with an image link and someone will edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same dataset "History2" as a field (column in report design) and as well as in parameter list. Create a different dataset with the required value and use that in parameter.